# Is it possible to have ansible retry only on certain conditions, success/fail on others?

Tags: ansible

I have a web service that I want to retry with a delay if I get a 409 status code.  Otherwise, I want it to exit immediately, either with success (2xx) or failure (anything else).

```yaml
- name: Change the database backup retention days from the default 7
  uri:
    url: "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{ subscription_id }}/resourceGroups/{{ resource_group }}/providers/Microsoft.DBforMariaDB/servers/{{ mariadb_server_name }}?api-version=2018-06-01-preview"
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ bearer_token }}"
    method: PATCH
    body_format: json
    body:
      properties:
        storageProfile:
          backupRetentionDays: 30
  register: results
```

This wont work, because it's going to retry more than 409.

```yaml
    retries: 1
    delay: 30
    failed_when: results.status >= 300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`until`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) loop with a generated list of all the 2xx codes as [`status_code`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-status_code).
The generated list can be done with the [`range`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-globals.range) function of Jinja.

This way, you will get an immediate a success for all 2xx code, an immediate failure for all other codes and a retry for the status code 409.

Here is an example:

```yaml
- uri:
    url: https://httpbin.org/status/409
    ## List containing all the 2xx codes that should be successful
    status_code: "{{ range(200, 300) }}"
  register: results
  retries: 1
  delay: 30
  until: results.status != 409
```

Using https://httpbin.org/, you can adapt the status code in the URL to see how the task reacts to different status codes.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  And httpbin.org is an amazing tool